# Need example on implementing MessageHeaders.WriteHeaderContents

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a custom header stored in a "string" variable, I need to replace the header of a outgoing SOAP request from my WCF client with the header in the "string" type variable. Based on research I see that implementing the `MessageHeaders.WriteHeaderContents` can work but this method accepts only `XmlDictionaryWriter` or `XmlWriter` types as input. I have a string input. How do I code in C# ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Message headers are a SOAP concept, and SOAP requests are XML documents, so you really need some XML-ness there. But for your scenario, you actually don't need to override `MessageHeaders`, you can use an inspector and simply replace the header at that point, as shown in the example below (the conversion to XML will be done by the `MessageHeader` class).

```
public class StackOverflow_7141998
{
    [MessageContract]
    public class MyMC
    {
        [MessageHeader(Name = "MyHeader", Namespace = "http://my.namespace.com")]
        public string HeaderValue { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember(Name = "MyBody", Namespace = "http://my.namespace.com")]
        public string BodyValue { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Process(MyMC mc);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public void Process(MyMC mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Header value: {0}", mc.HeaderValue);
        }
    }
    public class MyInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public string NewHeaderValue { get; set; }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            int originalIndex = request.Headers.FindHeader("MyHeader", "http://my.namespace.com");
            if (originalIndex >= 0)
            {
                request.Headers.Insert(originalIndex, MessageHeader.CreateHeader("MyHeader", "http://my.namespace.com", this.NewHeaderValue));
                request.Headers.RemoveAt(originalIndex + 1);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        MyInspector inspector = new MyInspector { NewHeaderValue = "Modified header value" };
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(inspector);
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.Process(new MyMC { HeaderValue = "Original header value", BodyValue = "The body" });

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you've created an endpoint variable in the Test, but you didn't use it. What is the purpose of this variable?

Comment: In this case, it is not needed - I have a template that I use for many of the WCF examples that I post, and sometimes we need to configure the endpoint (for example by adding a behavior). In this case I just forgot to remove the declaration.